# Alexa - Is there a way to get user information without account linking?

Tags: permissions, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-account-linking

I'd like to bypass account linking and grab users name, email and phone number.  Is there any way to do that?  I can't seem to find any documentation on how to bypass account linking and still grab user information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Customer Profile API.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html